Vuejs select box doesn't display default option
I have created three select boxes as mentioned in the Vuejs documentation but it doesn't display the disabled options as the default option. It just shows blank.
Do you know the reason or the solution to this issue? I tried to remove class attributes from the select boxes but it doesn't work

The code of the select boxes is below.
     <div class="canvas-area">
      <!-- Loop to create multiple canvases -->
      <div v-for="(page, index) in this.taleData.pages" :key="index" class="canvas-container">
         <div class="canvas-header">
          <p>Page {{ index + 1 }}</p>

          <select class="form-control mb-lg-1" v-model="selectedTextEffect[index]"
                  @change="applyTextEffect(index + 1)">
            <option disabled value="">Select effect</option>
            <option value="normal">Normal Text</option>
            <option value="glowing">Glowing Text</option>
          </select>
          <select class="form-control mb-lg-1" v-model="selectedFonts[index]" @change="changeFont(index + 1)">
            <option selected disabled value="">Font type</option>
            <option v-for="font in fontOptions" :value="font.val" :key="font.id">
              {{ font.val }}
            </option>
          </select>

          <select class="form-control mb-lg-1" v-model="selectedFontSizes[index]"
                  @change="changeFontSize(index + 1)">
            <option disabled value="">Font size</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="24" selected>24</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="32">32</option>
            <option value="36">36</option>
            <option value="40">40</option>
          </select>
        ...

  data() {
    return {
      bookDetails: null, // to store fetched book details
      textColor: '#ff9136',
      selectedFonts: {},
      selectedFontSizes: {},
      fontOptions: [
        {id: 1, val: 'Times New Roman'},
        {id: 2, val: 'Arial'},
        {id: 3, val: 'Courier New'},
      ],
      selectedTextEffect: {},
      canvasHistory: {},
    };
  },
  computed: {
    taleData() { // it's just a JSON data that comes from the backend
      return this.$store.getters.getTaleData;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    applyTextEffect(canvasIndex) {
      const effect = this.selectedTextEffect[canvasIndex - 1];
      const canvasComponentRef = this.$refs[`editorCanvas${canvasIndex}`];
      if (canvasComponentRef && canvasComponentRef.length > 0) {
        const canvas = canvasComponentRef[0].canvas;
        const activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject(); // Grouped text objects

    if (activeObject) {
      if (activeObject.type === 'group') {
        // Extract the first text object from the group
        const textObject = activeObject.getObjects().find(obj => obj.type === 'text' || obj.type === 'textbox');

        if (textObject) {
          // Capture properties from the first text object
          const {left, top, text, fontSize, fontFamily, textAlign, fill} = textObject;

          // Remove the group from the canvas
          canvas.remove(activeObject);

          // Create new text box with the same properties
          const newTextOptions = {
            left: 100,
            top: canvas.height - 180,
            width: canvas.width - 200,
            fontSize: fontSize,
            fill: fill,
            originY: 'top',
            originX: 'left',
            fontFamily: fontFamily,
            textAlign: textAlign,
          };
          this.addTextWithEffect(text, newTextOptions, effect, canvas);
        }
      } else {
        canvas.remove(activeObject);
        this.addTextWithEffect(activeObject.text, {
          left: 100,
          top: canvas.height - 180,
          width: canvas.width - 200,
          fontSize: activeObject.fontSize,
          fontFamily: activeObject.fontFamily,
          textAlign: activeObject.textAlign,
          fill: activeObject.fill
        }, effect, canvas);
      }
    }
  }
},


i need to see your script

@cantdocpp which parts? the whole code is 700 lines

selectedTextEffect and index for example

@cantdocpp added

I don't think i get your code. The selectedFontSizes and selectedTextEffect variables is blank

You need to make sure that selectedTextEffect[index] its value initially is emptyString "".

You need to share the code that is updating the value of these variables.

You can add selected for the option that you want to be selected by default.
<option selected value="">Select effect</option>
If you want user to not select that option again you can add selected disabled, so once a user select another option they can't select it again.
<option selected disabled value="">Select effect</option>
If you want to does not show that option in the options list but just want it be initially selected add selected hidden. This will make the option to be selected by default but will not display it in the options list.
<option selected hidden value="">Select effect</option>

I made this already in the second select box, but it didn't work

Then please create a reproducible code like code sandbox so that it will be easier to help you.
